# How can I access the size of a symbol as set by .size directive in C

Tags: c, assembly, gnu

I have set the size of a symbol in assembly using the `.size` directive of GNU assembler, how do I access this size in C?

```
void my_func(void){}

asm(
    "_my_stub:\n\t"
    "call my_func\n\t"
    ".size _my_stub, .-_my_stub"
);

extern char* _my_stub;

int main(){
    /* print size of _my_stub here */
}
```

Here is relevant objdump

```
0000000000000007 <_my_stub>:
_my_stub():
   7:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  c <main>
```

Here is relevant portion of readelf

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 14 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     5: 0000000000000007     5 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 _my_stub
```

I can see from the objdump and symbol table that the size of _my_stub is 5. How can I get this value in C?

Comment: How about replacing `.size` with `hhh: .long .-_my_stub` and `extern const int gfoo asm("hhh");`?  I can't try it here, but I expect you should be able to `printf("%d\n", gfoo);`.

Comment: I've asked myself the same question.  The symbol size is not accessible and as there is no relocation for it, there is no way to use it in a program.

Comment: Is there any way to use the symbol size in assembly? Surely there must be a way to access this value in code otherwise the `.size` directive would be useless.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Size.html#Size), for COFF outputs, `.size` must be within a `.def/.endef`.  Looking at [.def](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Def.html#Def), we see that it's used to *Begin defining debugging information for a symbol name*.  While ELF doesn't have the same nesting requirement, it seems plausible to assume that's how it's used there too.  If this is only intended to be used by debuggers, it (kinda) makes sense that there's no way to access it from within the assembler.

Comment: Thanks for the help @DavidWohlferd. Do you want to put your comments in an answer so that I best answer it?

Comment: @HassanNadeem The `.size` directive is only strictly needed for common blocks where it is used by the linker to determine the size of said block. Otherwise, it's just decoration for use with `nm -S`.

Comment: You probably want `jmp my_func` to tailcall.  If you use `call`, the `my_func` will eventually return to whatever's after the `call` instruction, unless it never returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to access the size attribute from within gas.  As an alternative, how about replacing `.size` with

```
hhh:
.long .-_my_stub     # 32-bit integer constant, regardless of the size of a C long
```

and

```
extern const uint32_t gfoo asm("hhh");
 // asm("asm_name") sidesteps the _name vs. name issue across OSes
```

I can't try it here, but I expect you should be able to `printf("%ld\n", gfoo);`.  I tried using `.equ` so this would be a constant rather than allocating memory for it, but I never got it to work right.

This does leave the question as to the purpose of the `.size` attribute.  Why set it if you you can't read it?  I'm not an expert, but I've got a theory:

According to the [docs](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Size.html#Size), for COFF outputs, `.size` must be within a `.def/.endef`. Looking at [.def](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Def.html#Def), we see that it's used to *Begin defining debugging information for a symbol name*.

While ELF doesn't have the same nesting requirement, it seems plausible to assume that debugging is the intent there too. If this is only intended to be used by debuggers, it (kinda) makes sense that there's no way to access it from within the assembler.

Comment: In x86-64 System V, a C `long` is 64 bits.  In GAS, [`.int` and `.long`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Long.html#Long) are both always 32 bits for x86 and x86-64.  I'd suggest using `extern const uint32_t gfoo_size asm("hhh");`.  (And instead of replacing, possibly just adding that after the `.size` directive).  Also would be better to place this in `.rodata`, not mixed with the functions, but first you have to capture the size into an assembler constant before changing sections.  Or put labels at start/end and do `.pushsection .rodata` ; `.int end - start` ; `.popsection`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just want to get the size of a subset of a code segment or data segment. Here is an assembly example (GAS&AT style) you can refer to:

```
target_start:
// Put your code segment or data segment here
// ...
target_end = .

// Use .global to export the label
.global target_size
target_size = target_end - target_start
```

In C/C++ source file, you can use label `target_size` by `extern long target_size`.

Note: this example hasn't been tested.

Comment: Since the linker symbol behaves like an address, use (size_t)&target_size to get the size value in C code.